# loading homepage from Ini file error on formcreate

Tags: delphi, browser

I created a small webbrowser and I remembered the homepage in an Ini file. When I run this under formcreate I get an error. When I remover the webbrowser.navigate I dont get the error anymore. How should i put this code up if I want my webbrowser to go straight to the homepage when I open the program? Code is below

```
    web1:=startIni.ReadString('homepage' ,'web1','<None>');
    IEAddress1.Text:= web1;
    Embeddedwb1.Go(web1);
```

Comment: -1. You need to describe what "an error" means.

Answer (score 6):

The browser needs a message loop which is ususally not running yet in the main form's `OnCreate` event. Try navigating the first time `OnShow` is called.

Alternatively, from `OnCreate` post a message to self and navigate the browser in the message handler - this is how it's done in the CoolStuff demo which came with older versions of Delphi.